# Android Firebase Push Notification Double values

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hi all i am implementing Firebase Push notifications in Android. Everything is working fine except when i am retrieving the messages, they are duplicated twice. I tried debugging a whole day but could not succeed. Help me out please!
I am using shared preferences for storing the message. And i am sending through Api and its topic based.

Below is my onMessageReceived() method code of my MyFirebaseMessagingService class

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
      Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");

    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("mypreference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String prev = sp.getString("msg", "-");
    String newp;
    if(prev != "-"){
      newp = prev+","+messageBody;
    }else{
      newp = messageBody;
    }

   Log.d("prev123",prev);

   SharedPreferences.Editor e = sp.edit();
   e.putString("msg",newp);
   Log.d("afterstore", newp);
   e.commit();
   e.apply();
}
```

And the class where I am showing the message is:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
 super.onResume();
 String msg = sp.getString("msg", null);
 Log.d("message", msg);
 String[] pqrs = msg.split(",");

 Log.d("Array msg",pqrs);

 ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,pqrs);
 listView.setAdapter(adp);
```

In Log once message is received it shows but just after fraction of second same message is appended to the log. Don't know how. Please help.

Comment: just a thinking, don't do that retrieve on onResume(), do that onCreate() and see what happens.

Comment: Please post your other classes about firebase

Comment: Hi @msh.nayan I tried that as well still the problem persists

Comment: @EmreAkturk I don't think other classes are relevant.

Comment: after receiving data on onMessageReceived() & after storing those data on Shared Preference & commit it; can u retrieve the data immediately to verify when double data is store or not

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it what's exactly duplicated. İf it's data that you saved it may be the reason that you save it twice.

```
e.commit(); 
e.apply()
```

Just use one of them. They do same operation unlike async or sync.

Good luck

Emre

Comment: Thanks @Emre for your valuable answer. I tried removing e.commit() but didn't help.

Comment: So onMessageReceived called twice?

Comment: Its called once only. I guess the problem is when i am storing it in shared preferences, there it is stored twice

Answer (score 0):

Did you clear data of application after removing commit line? You might test with old duplicated data after fix?

Also if your calling intent in other classes, give it  a try to remove it. As I know it's calling automatically by base classes of firebase.

Comment: Yeah I deleted the app data